# Fetching json array, null pointer refrence exception

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception

```
{"names":["name1","name2","name3","name4"]}
```

I need to fetch this and show them in a list. What I am doing is

```
public class brand
{  public string Name
    { get; set; }
}

public class brands
{  public list<brand> Names
    { get; set; }
```

}

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getdata();
    }

    private void getdata()
    {
        string uri = "URL";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));

        req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(show), req);
    }

    private void show(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        StreamReader stream1 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());


         string s1 = stream1.ReadToEnd();
         var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(brands));
         var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s1));


          var bb = (brands)ser.ReadObject(stream);


          foreach (var ev in bb.Names)
            {
                textBlock1.Text = ev.Name.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This I made after reading blog posts. I am getting `NullReferenceException`.
Please tell me where I am doing wrong or alternative way to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First learn how to parse your JSON data. Consider this as a json string.

```
String jsonData = @"{""names"":[""name1"",""name2"",""name3"",""name4""]}";

var brands = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Brands>(jsonData);
foreach (var item in brands.names)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Where your Brands class is like this

```
public class Brands
    {
        public List<string> names { get; set; }
    }
```

This above code explains how to parse your json data. Now, coming to fetching your json data from web service, as your request is not a POST request (it appears to be get from your code), you can use a simple WebCleint.

```
void getData()
{
  WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
  webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("url"));
}

void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    var brands = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Brands>(e.Result);
    foreach (var item in brands.names)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Check this blog for any other doubts : [Parsing JSON in a Windows Phone Application](http://nkishorchandra.blogspot.in/2012/10/parsing-json-in-windows-phone.html)